# Generic methods with delegate parameters

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I'm trying to create two generic methods, one of them is void and the other has a return type. The void method takes an `Action` delegate, and the other one takes a `Func` delegate. The implementation for the void method is like this:

```
 public static void ExecuteVoid<T>(Action<T> actionToExecute)
    {
        string endpointUri = ServiceEndpoints.GetServiceEndpoint(typeof(T));

        using (ChannelFactory<T> factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(endpointUri)))
        {
            T proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

            actionToExecute(proxy);
        }
    }
```

This works fine, but I'm having issues with the non-void method:

```
public static T ExecuteAndReturn<T>(Func<T> delegateToExecute)
    {
        string endpointUri = ServiceEndpoints.GetServiceEndpoint(typeof(T));

        T valueToReturn;

        using (ChannelFactory<T> factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(endpointUri)))
        {
            T proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

            valueToReturn = delegateToExecute();
        }

        return valueToReturn;
    }
```

Now when I try to make a call to the method like this:

```
var result = ServiceFactory.ExecuteAndReturn((IMyService x) => x.Foo());
```

I get this compile error:

```
The type arguments for method 'ServiceFactory.ExecuteAndReturn<T>(System.Func<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

`Foo()` in this case is a method with no arguments that returns an `object`. I then tried to call the method by specifying the type explicitly:

```
var result = ServiceFactory.ExecuteAndReturn<IMyService>(x => x.Foo());
```

but now I'm getting another exception saying

```
Delegate 'IMyService' does not take 1 arguments.
```

I'm really lost here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the definition of IMyService?

Comment: @terrybozzio What would be type of `x` in this case then? The type needs to be specified somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be confusing the return type with the proxy type. If you specify your argument as `Func<T>`, then `T` needs to be the return type of the function, not the proxy type. However, you also need to specify the proxy type, in order to get the proper service endpoint and channel factory. Thus, you actually need *two* type parameters: one for the proxy and one for the return type. I'm also assuming that the function delegate needs to take the initialized proxy as parameter; otherwise, this wrapper method would be pointless.

```
public static TResult ExecuteAndReturn<TProxy, TResult>(
    Func<TProxy, TResult> delegateToExecute)
{
    string endpointUri = ServiceEndpoints.GetServiceEndpoint(typeof(TProxy));

    TResult valueToReturn;

    using (ChannelFactory<TProxy> factory = new ChannelFactory<TProxy>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(endpointUri)))
    {
        TProxy proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        valueToReturn = delegateToExecute(proxy);
    }

    return valueToReturn;
}
```

**Edit**: The compiler error arose because `(IMyService x) => x.Foo()` is not compatible with the `Func<T>` delegate. When writing anonymous functions, the inferred type is that of the anonymous function itself, not the method it happens to call. In this case, the anonymous function accepts a single parameter of type `IMyService`, and returns `object` (being the return type of `Foo`). Thus, the correct delegate for this anonymous method would be `Func<IMyService, object>`.

Comment: I believe I've actually written something very similar to this wrapper method in the past, so it felt familiar ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your argument as `func<x>` ie delegate with no parameters but then calling it as `Func<x,y>` ie a delegate that takes 1 parameter, IMyService, hence the error "Delegate 'IMyService' does not take 1 arguments"